# How to simulate mouse clicks without installing any packages?

Tags: command-line

I am looking for a way to simulate mouse click at the same position like 10 times per second. I know this can easily be achieved using `xdotools` but I am currently on a machine without the possibility to install additional software.

So is there a possibility to achieve this just with a plain terminal?

Comment: Does the machine have python installed?

Comment: yes, but I have no experience in programming phython...

Comment: I will get back to you later today. I'm currently at school with no access to Ubuntu.

Comment: Back home now :) May I ask what you're using it for, and why you cannot install software?